# Assign function to row

Tags: jquery

I have the following function that changes row color based on a particular selection. it works fine if there's only one row.

```
function myFunc() {
    var opt = $(".mySelector").val();
    if (opt == "left") {
        $(".mySelector").closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","red");
    } else if (opt == "right") {
        $(".mySelector").closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","green");
    }
}
$(".mySelector").change(function(){
    myFunc();
});

myFunc();

<table>
<tr>
    <td>val 1</td>
    <td>val 2</td>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
        <option value="left">red</option>
        <option value="right">green</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

however, if I add more rows, they all get the same color... clearly i need to differentiate them somehow...

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>val 1</td>
    <td>val 2</td>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
        <option value="left">red</option>
        <option value="right">green</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>val 3</td>
    <td>val 4</td>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
        <option value="left">red</option>
        <option value="right">green</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the selector again, use `this`.

```
function myFunc() {
    var opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt == "left") {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","red");
    } else if (opt == "right") {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","green");
    }
}

$(".mySelector").change(myFunc).change(); //Call change twice.  The first will add the callback and the second will trigger a change event on each .mySelector element.
```

Comment: This will work on change, but how would I change the colors on page load? Thanks.

Comment: an afterthought... Is there a way to determin whether the row is odd or even and assign the css row color id opt is neither left nor right?

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").index()` will get the index of the row, which you can test for evenness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement loop for going through all the `mySelectors`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the `.relationship` element is in you HTML. Do you mean to bind the `change` event to `.mySelector`? If so, this would solve it:

```
function myFunc($this) {
    var opt = $this.val();
    if (opt == "left") {
        $this.closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","red");
    } else if (opt == "right") {
        $this.closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","green");
    }
}
$(".mySelector").change(function(){
    myFunc($(this));
});
```

Basically, you need to pass a reference to the element that has changed as an argument to the `myFunc()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this), like:

```
function myFunc($obj) {
    var opt = $obj;
    if (opt == "left") {
        $(".mySelector").closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","red");
    } else if (opt == "right") {
        $(".mySelector").closest("tr").find("td").css("background-color","green");
    }
}
$(".mySelector").change(function(){
    myFunc($obj);
});
```